# Input and output do not equal in jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Why is the text of the paragraph always one letter behind?

Shouldn't it automatically "copy" the value of the input to the paragraph and always be the same text?

How can I fix this problem?

```js
$(function() {
  $("input").keydown(function() {
    $("p").text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
<p></p>
```

Comment: New value is created on `keyup` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the keyup event, it works as you desire. I believe this is because the keydown event fires before the value is populated into the text field, so it cannot be used.

Answer (score 3):

On `.keydown()`, the value has not yet propagated to the form element. Try `.keyup()`. (There's also `.change()`, which only triggers once the element loses focus.)

Comment: Ah right, amended my answer, thanks @Mohamed-Yousef!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that every time event `keydown`, of the input element, is fired the value have not changed..

Try with jQuery [.keyup()](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/):

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {
  $('p').text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the use of `input` event instead since it's more efficient when tracking the user input's :

```
$('input').on('input', function() {
  $('p').text($(this).val());
});
```

For multiple `input/paragraph` you could use the `.next()` function to target the related `p` :

```
 $('input').on('input', function() {
  $(this).next('p').text($(this).val());
});
```

Code:

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  $(this).next('p').text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input>
<p></p>
<input>
<p></p>
<input>
<p></p>
<input>
<p></p>
<input>
<p></p>
```

Comment: one more question. If I had multiple input fields and multiple paragraphs, how can I assign one input field to one paragraph in jQuery?